# Calculating the number of id's from a felm estimation

Tags: r, panel, plm

I'm estimating a series of country and year fixed-effects panel models using the felm function. I would like to calculate the number of countries included in each estimation. I can easily do this if I run my regressions using the plm function, as shown below. However, I don't want to run my regressions using plm for other reasons. Is there a way of calculating the number of id's used in a felm estimation?
a sample code is given below:

```
library(plm); library(lfe)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
reg_plm <- plm(inv ~ value + capital,   data = Grunfeld, model = "within", effect = "twoways")
reg_felm <- felm(inv ~ value + capital  | 
                  firm + year, data=Grunfeld)

pdim(reg_plm)[["panel.names"]]$id.names
```

Note that my data is an unbalanced panel and pdim does not work with a felm object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str(reg_felm)` - as it is usual in such cases, in search of objects -  reveals that the fixed effects are stored in `fe`.

We could display the `levels`

```
levels(reg_felm$fe$firm)
# [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

where their number is

```
length(levels(reg_felm$fe$firm))
# [1] 10
```

or use a `table` to see if it's balanced.

```
reg_felm$fe$firm |> table()
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
# 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use `nlevels`

```
nlevels(reg_felm$fe$firm)
```